# TestFlight push notifications are not working on my iPhone

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, testflight

I am not receiving any push notifications after uploading my application to AppStore on TestFlight. I set the push notification pem file to `aps_production`, and have followed all the valid steps as far as I can tell. If anyone has faced this issue before, then I would appreciate you help.

Comment: So you got the notifications in developer mode right?..

Comment: Fixed capitalization and grammar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the distribution provisioning profile you're using to send your application to Apple Store enables push notifications.

You can check this at Apple's developer site: 
Certificates,Identifiers & Profiles -> Provisioning Profiles

[image: Expanded provisioning profile]